# Why does this gives me error: "DataTables warning: table id=example - Requested unknown parameter 'id'

Tags: datatables

I am trying to implement add row in jquery datatable ie when the user clicks on add row button, it adds a new row
I tried to follow this example: https://datatables.net/examples/api/add_row.html

But it gives me error as:

> DataTables warning: table id=example - Requested unknown parameter 'id' for row >4, column 0. For more information about this error, please see >http://datatables.net/tn/4

When I press OK to the error it adds row but no data is added.

I have created my sample at this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/aman1981/x7jstfw1/30/

Below is just the part of adding row:

```
var t = $('#example').DataTable();
var counter = 1;

$('#addRow').on( 'click', function () {
    t.row.add( [
        counter +'.1',
        counter +'.2'
    ] ).draw( false );

    counter++;
} );
```

Thanks for looking into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest fix is to add the data like you did with Allan and Bob, as an object.

```
$('#addRow').on( 'click', function () {
    t.row.add( {
        "id": counter +'.1',
        "name": counter +'.2'
    } ).draw( false );
```

See the fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/x7jstfw1/31/

Comment: Thanks this works fine. One ques though, I am using knockout to bind. If I move the code and bind the button click to observable its doest like "id":" counter +'.1' . Any idea how can this be sorted. I have updated the jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/aman1981/x7jstfw1/38/

Comment: Yep, you're passing the new row as an array ('[]'), it needs to be an object ('{}') - see this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/48p5bdmz/2/

Comment: My bad, missed that one. Thanks for the help